# Xamarin: how do I change the color of a button added in code?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin app creates buttons in code. I can change the color of a button I click, as the button is referenced in its Clicked handler's sender argument, but I want to change the color of buttons that I didn't click. The problem is, how do I find the buttons I want to change?

I thought about using FindByName, but Name doesn't appear to be an attribute.

One way I can think of: loop through all of the buttons until I find the one with the StyleId of the desired button. Is there an easier way than that?

Answer (score 1):

when you create a button in code you need to keep a reference to it, like you would with any C# object you want to reference later

```
Button MyButton = new Button { ... };
MyButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Purple;
```

if you need to access it from multiple places in your code, you should declare it as a **class level** variable to that it has scope throughout your class

Comment: re-read your question, updated example to use code, not XAML

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to find the button created in code behind without XAML, like @Jason said, use the variable name of the Button you created or set it directly.**

```
 Button button = new Button { ClassId = "button1", BackgroundColor = Color.Red };
```

**If you want to access a view with `FindByName`, you need to create the button with `x:Name` in XAML.**

There is an XAML example:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" ></Button>
```

And in your code behind you could do something like:

```
 button1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

If you need to find a view in xaml for some reason, do this:

```
var button = this.FindByName<Button>("button1");
button.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```